# How to implement "lightning:tree" variants as "Grid"?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps, lightning-design-system

**How to implement "lightning:tree" variants "Grid" ?**

Ref: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_tree.htm

**In the following code they have used "base" variant, But now i need to implement the same using "Grid" variant.**

**How to achieve "Grid" Variant ?**

Ref: https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/trees/?state=expanded&variant=grid

**Component:**

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
    <aura:attribute name="items" type="Object"/>
    <lightning:tree items="{! v.items }" header="Roles"/>
</aura:component>
```

**JS:**

```
({
    doInit: function (cmp, event, helper) {
    var items = [{
            "label": "Western Sales Director",
            "name": "1",
            "expanded": true,
            "items": [{
                "label": "Western Sales Manager",
                "name": "2",
                "expanded": true,
                "items" :[{
                    "label": "CA Sales Rep",
                    "name": "3",
                    "expanded": true,
                    "items" : []
                },{
                    "label": "OR Sales Rep",
                    "name": "4",
                    "expanded": true,
                    "items" : []
                }]
            }]
        }, {
            "label": "Eastern Sales Director",
            "name": "5",
            "expanded": false,
            "items": [{
                "label": "Easter Sales Manager",
                "name": "6",
                "expanded": true,
                "items" :[{
                    "label": "NY Sales Rep",
                    "name": "7",
                    "expanded": true,
                    "items" : []
                }, {
                    "label": "MA Sales Rep",
                    "name": "8",
                    "expanded": true,
                    "items" : []
                }]
            }]
        }];
        cmp.set('v.items', items);
    }     
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not yet implemented in the Lightning Component System. By the time that salesforce.com finishes implementing all the components, it will most likely be available as a `lightning:treeGrid` or something like that. For now, if you need it, you will have to build it yourself.